# Booting up my iMac

Tags: command-line, boot, mac

I can’t boot up my iMac, can’t even go into single user mode. If I boot up to recovery mode( command r upon power button) it will load online but till loading bar is finish downloading, it will go into a blank screen. Can someone help me please, I’m using a late 2012 iMac. Appreciate your help. Thanks

---

Tried booting up using my external drive but but it still won’t boot up. I also tried connecting it with my macbook (operating)using firewire but still can’t. Last time when it used to be able to boot using single user mode ,, I remebered it says it can’t boot up due to an invalid integer or something which I don’t fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've see something like in the past.  Try going into recovery and then clicking the red x on the window after it loads.  It might (hopefully) ask for you to choose a startup disk.  Click the internal drive and let it reboot normally.

Comment: Thanks James ,,, but I don’t even get to see the red x to click... just the loading bar and then straight away it will go blank. Appreciate your answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Are you able to boot it to an external drive (if you have one)?

Answer (score -1):

Purchase a bootable OS on a flash drive (High Sierra) and plug it in. Restart and hold cmnd+R to boot into a screen with your new bootable drive. Select it and install. That should do it.

You can purchase a bootable disk here. https://www.ecrater.com/p/30535687/apple-macos-high-sierra-1013-1012-upgrade?gps=1&id=115931170339&gclid=CjwKCAiAhp_jBRAxEiwAXbniXStA7xBFPB1_yWMarmSBz8YNRTjbA4Y5tKycOaxzUEkPIkqLFprUGRoC6dQQAvD_BwE

If that doesn't work, your computer is probably fried. You'd need to swap parts one at a time to find out which one(s) broke. And since it's a Mac, that's probably not a good solution. You most likely need a new computer. Or you could always contact Apple support and see if they can help.